# How to use primefaces tree to download a file

Tags: java, jsf, tree, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.0.M2 with backing bean to add files arranged in folders (modules) and subfolders(assignments). I have managed to do that successfully, but I can't have control over the file to make it downloadable. I want to make the file as a button to download that specific file instead of just being a normal text. Please check the jsf code below:

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{files.root}" var="doc" selectionMode="single"
     selection="#{files.selectedTreeNode}">
            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{doc}"/>
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
```

Here is my backing bean class:

```
public class FilesBean implements Serializable {

private TreeNode root;

 public TreeNode getRoot() {
     root = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);
     TreeNode general = new DefaultTreeNode("General", root);
     TreeNode module = null;
     TreeNode assignment = null;
     TreeNode fileNode = null;

     if(getMoudles()!=null)
     {
        for(String s : getMoudles())
        {
                module = new DefaultTreeNode(s, root);
                if(getAssignments()!=null)
                {
                    for (Assignments as : getAssignments())
                    {
                        if(as.getMoudleid().equals(s))
                        assignment = new DefaultTreeNode(as.getAssignmentsPK().getAssignmentid(), module);

                        for(Files file : getFiles())
                        {
                            if (file.getFilesPK().getAssignmentid().equals(as.getAssignmentsPK().getAssignmentid()) && file.getThemodule().equals(s))
                            {fileNode = new DefaultTreeNode(file,assignment);}
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
     }

     return root;
 }
```

PS: PrimeFaces 3.0.M2, JSF 2.0, J2EE 6 Web, Servlet 3.0, Glassfish 3.0, EJB 3.0, browser: IE8 also tried on FireFox 3.6.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a `<p:commandButton>` with `<p:fileDownload>`?

```
<p:commandButton
        value="Download"
        title="Download"
        image="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
        ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{myBean.fileStreamedContent}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

In your backing bean (for example purposes, assuming your files are JPEGs):

```
public StreamedContent getFileStreamedContent() {
    try {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
           new FileInputStream("/your/file/path/fileXYZ.jpg"));
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/jpeg", "fileXYZ.jpg");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

The last part is associating a particular file with a particular tree node. You can use the `<p:tree>` attributes `selectionMode="single"` and `selection="#{myBean.selectedTreeNode}"`. The user selects a tree node and this will cause the `selectedTreeNode` to be set (via a setter method) on your bean.

```
private TreeNode selectedTreeNode;

public void setSelectedTreeNode(TreeNode selectedTreeNode) {
    this.selectedTreeNode = selectedTreeNode;
    if (this.selectedTreeNode != null) {
        Object yourTreeNodeData = this.selectedTreeNode.getData();
        // do whatever you need to do with the data object...
    }
}
```

In the `getFileStreamedContent()` method, just use the filename stored in your tree node object as the parameter to the `FileInputStream()` constructor.

**EDIT**

Rather than try to embed command buttons in the tree, provide one command button somewhere on the page. When a tree node is selected it can set the associated file (to be downloaded) as a property on your bean. Make your tree look like this:

```
<p:tree
        value="#{myBean.rootTreeNode}"
        var="node"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{myBean.selectedTreeNode}">
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{myBean.onNodeSelect}" />
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{myBean.onNodeUnselect}" />
</p:tree>

public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    // put some logging here...
}

public void onNodeUnselect(NodeUnselectEvent event) {
    // put some logging here...
}
```

Put a println or logging statement in your `setSelectedTreeNode` method to make sure the setter is being invoked when you click the tree node. Use the `getData()` method on the `TreeNode` to get back the data value that you originally put in it when you created the tree. The `getFileStreamedContent()` method will use that value to deliver the correct file that the user selected by clicking on a tree node.

Comment: This answer assumes that you're using PrimeFaces 3.0, since you didn't specify

Comment: No I'm using PrimeFaces 2.2.1. Thanks for the answer Jim, I havent tried it yet, Im gonna try it now! cheers

Comment: I have used the command button option, but whenever I put command button in the tree, neither the treeNodes get rendered nor the command button.

Comment: I put a printing statement in the setSelectedTreeNode for testing the node selection as u said, but when its not getting invoked when I select the node.

Comment: I added some more code. I didn't think the `<p:ajax>` was needed unless you wanted to add an event listener, but maybe it is required. Again, my code uses PrimeFaces 3.0 so I can't guarantee that it will work with the older PrimeFaces line.

Comment: When I add <p:ajax> into the <p:tree> it gives me this message: <p:ajax> Parent not an instance of ClientBehaviorHolder: org.primefaces.component.tree.Tree@2616df83
. + I have upgraded to PrimeFaces 3.0 but still have the same problem

Comment: I have also tried to put an onNodeClick attribute to the tree to invoke that method. But it didnt render the tree again.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and put in your updated code? Also include your JSF version, PrimeFaces version, container type and browser type and version.

Comment: Hi jim, please check the updated code and the PS. Thanx a lot

Comment: I'm going to throw an idea out there that might work better for you. There is another PrimeFaces control called `<p:treeTable>` that is quite similar to `<p:tree>`. It uses the same objects on the server side (`TreeNode` objects, etc) but will require some changes to your Facelet code. I just abandoned `<p:tree>` in my app because it was way too buggy in IE. I replaced it with `<p:treeTable>` and it works great. Check it out on the PrimeFaces Labs Showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeTable.jsf. Their example sounds quite similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks jim, Im going to try it now, but do you know what is the data type Document that is used in the constructor of DefaultTreeNode?

Comment: `Document` is just a class that was made up to demonstrate their example. Your best approach is to download the complete PrimeFaces 3.0 Showcase WAR file, unzip it, and copy the pieces used for their `<p:treeTable>` example. That's what I did, and then just deleted the bits that I didn't need once I had it working. You will want to get the following files out of their Showcase WAR: Document.java, treeTable.xhtml. Just copy-and-paste the content that you need from them into your existing project and modify it to suit your needs. PS: If this works for you, please accept my answer here. :)

Comment: Go here http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html and look for the Component Showcase link at the bottom of the page to download the WAR.

Comment: Hi I managed to use the treetable and it worked, but the problem is that it takes ages to render; more than 40 seconds to render the table each time it is called. So I decided to do it in an Ajax engine and simply load the files everytime with a button click. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Did you try using the lazy loading features of the tree table to deal with the long loading time?